# Textbooks on basic algebra (with exercises)

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, inequality, polynomials, systems-of-equations

I am looking for textbooks (ideally with a lot of exercises) on basic algebra.

In particular, I am interested in the following topics:

- basic calculations with real and complex numbers
- use and applications of polynomial with real or complex coefficients with one or several variables (remarkable identity, zeros, polynomial division, factorisation)
- rational fraction
- first degree problems (equation with 1 variable, n x n system with 1 parameter, inequality, system of inequalities with 1 variable)
- second degree problems (equation with 1 variable with real or complex coefficients, roots, inequality with real coefficients)
- combinatorial analysis, binomial theorem, Pascal's triangle
- arithmetic and geometric progression

Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: many of the points are topics that are not about algebra, by example combinatorics, or progressions. By the other hand textbooks have necessarily exercises, otherwise they aren't textbooks.

Answer (score 0):

There are many books that you can use. For some of the topics such as binomial theorem, pascals triangle etc the book '***discrete mathematics with applications by susanna epp***' is good. Whilst any book titled '***College algebra***' would be suitable for the rest.

Note: If you wish to cover complex numbers in any detail, a complex variable book would be needed. A decent one is ***Complex Analysis: A First Course with Applications
Book by Dennis G.***